# How to hide metaboxes in WordPress Admin on WooCommerce "Add Product" page - Remove side sortables for a specific user role

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, admin, metabox

How do I hide certain metaboxes in WordPress Admin screen options for specific user roles?

For example, I allow the user role "Store Vendor" to access the WordPress admin to upload their products to my marketplace, but I do not want them to access some features.

Ideally there would be a filter to add in the functions.php but I can't figured it.

IDs that need to be removed from admin menu for Store Vendor:

`uap_affiliate_landing_page`

`ihc_show_for`

`ihc_drip_content`

`wcfm-view`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try maybe **WPFront User Role Editor** plugin, it is free but also has premium features.
Hope this helps if not very sorry, i m not into codes much only as hobby.